# Problem in returning values with my procedure

Tags: mysql, procedure

The following procedure is not returning values. Whats wrong?

```
CREATE PROCEDURE `sp_ValidarLogin`
    (pEmail VARCHAR(45), 
    pSenha VARCHAR(255),
    OUT rId INT,
    OUT rNome VARCHAR(45),
    OUT rDataNascimento DATE)
    SELECT @rId = ID, 
            @rNome = NOME, 
            @rDataNascimento = DATA_NASCIMENTO 
        FROM usuario 
    WHERE EMAIL = pEmail AND SENHA = pSenha;


CALL sp_ValidarLogin ('rcaldas.ti@gmail.com','1234', @id, @nome, @nascimento);--its correct
select @id, @nome, @nascimento;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use `:=` instead of `=` to assign values on `SELECT`:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE `sp_ValidarLogin` (
    pEmail VARCHAR(45), 
    pSenha VARCHAR(255),
    OUT rId INT,
    OUT rNome VARCHAR(45),
    OUT rDataNascimento DATE)
    SELECT @rId := ID, @rNome := NOME, @rDataNascimento := DATA_NASCIMENTO 
    FROM usuario 
    WHERE EMAIL = pEmail AND SENHA = pSenha;
```

[**demo on dbfiddle.uk**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=72db7132f3ebfdc903ab4849f97f1cfd)

> Previous releases of MySQL made it possible to assign a value to a user variable in statements other than `SET`. This functionality is supported in MySQL 8.0 for backward compatibility but is subject to removal in a future release of MySQL.
>
> When making an assignment in this way, you must use `:=` as the assignment operator; `=` is treated as the comparison operator in statements other than `SET`.
>
> **source:** https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/user-variables.html